# Is Doctrine2 too 'big' for this project?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I'm writing an application that manages something like Drupal's nodes.  I'm planning on using the app in various content management systems / applications (Concrete5, Wordpress, custom Zend & Yii applications, etc...).

Since I'm using it in so many different places, I have to package an ORM with the app (ie I can't use Conrete5's or Yii's ORM, etc...).  I love Doctrine 2, but am concerned that this is too 'big' of an orm to be packaged with my app.

It get's messy, for example, if I'm incorporating this app with a Zend application which is running Doctrine 2.  I don't want two 'instances' of Doctrine running in the same app.  Is this a warranted concern?

Question:  Is Doctrine 2 too 'big' for this project?  If so, what would be a good alternative ORM?

Comment: i always go and check my domain model before making these decisions. if it's too messy or has many complicated relationships i stick to doctrine. what about yours?

Comment: There's not a lot going on.  Im probably going to write a decorator for PDO to give it some more functionality and use that.

Comment: if you want to keep using ORM you might want to have a look at [RedBeanPHP](http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use your application as an extension for other CMSes and/or frameworks,you should definitley use an ORM for the following reasons which comes to my mind:

1.CMS database installations are different.some use mysql some use oracle ,etc and you will have to create your own adapters or

2.Use CMS's native database abstraction layers.So you will have to rerwite your own model for every cms plugin you are gonna make.

3.Doctrine can do many big jobs but using doctrine is rather easy.doctrine is not resources intensive.

4.using more than one instance of doctrine will not be a problem as far as i know.

5.however doctrine2 requires minimum installation of PHP 5.3 and some shared servers might have older versions of php which this problem will be resolved while time passes and 5.2 becomes obsolete.

However in some CMSes more than one connection will made for your extension to work.(one for the CMS'S native database queries and one for your doctrine query.)

Answer (score 0):

Way 1: work with different ORM's via adapters

- (+) better integration with frameworks
- (-) a lot of work to implement adapters
- (-) loss of flexibility (limited by your adapters interface)

Way 2 (my choice):  Use PDO with FETCH_CLASS, it's comfortable enough (you can fetch data to instances of your classes). Most of modern ORM's on PHP works through PDO, so integration must be easy.

Also about Doctrine 2 & Yii -- I tested this combination, works fine.